# MySQL query with subtraction between count of two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have 4 MySQL tables:

**designer**: `id`, `name`

**game**: `id`, `name`, `designer_id`

**started**: `id`, `game_id`

**finished**: `id`, `game_id`

My app adds a row to `started` when a game starts. It adds a row to `finished` when the game is finished. I want to get the total count of started but not finished games, grouped by designer name. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT designer.name, COUNT(started.game_id) AS total FROM started 
  LEFT JOIN game ON started.game_id = game.id 
  LEFT JOIN designer ON game.designer_id = designer.id 
  GROUP BY designer.name
```

This gets me the total count of started games, grouped by their designer. But it doesn't take into account the fact that I only want started *and not finished* games.

I tried subtracting the totals, like this:

```
SELECT designer.name, (COUNT(started.game_id) - COUNT(finished.game_id)) AS total 
  FROM started 
  LEFT JOIN game ON started.game_id = game.id 
  LEFT JOIN designer ON game.designer_id = designer.id 
  LEFT JOIN finished ON finished.game_id = started.game_id
  GROUP BY designer.name
```

But this returns totals of `0`, although there are more started than finished games.

Example data:

**designer**

```
id | name
--------------
1  | Jim Smith
```

**game**

```
id | name | designer_id
-----------------------
1  | Test | 1
```

**started**

```
id | game_id
------------
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 1
```

**finished**

```
id | game_id
------------
1  | 1
2  | 1
```

Comment: You should really include some sample data in your question.

Comment: It seems mistakenly you joined finished table on started.id instead of started.game_id

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, I've added sample data

Comment: I would revise the schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT s.game_id FROM started s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM finished
  WHERE game_id = s.game_id
)
```

or with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT s.game_id 
FROM started s LEFT JOIN finished f
ON f.game_id = s.game_id
WHERE f.id IS NULL
```

you can get all the game ids that started but not finished.
Then use any of the 2 above queries to get the results you want by joining only `designer` and `game` like this:

```
SELECT 
  d.name, 
  COUNT(g.id) AS total 
FROM designer d INNER JOIN game g
ON d.id = g.designer_id
WHERE g.id IN (
  SELECT s.game_id FROM started s
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM finished
    WHERE game_id = s.game_id
  ) 
)
GROUP BY d.id, d.name
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all , i suggest to change your database design and convert started table and finished table into one , with state field that defines the game is finished or not ( Its just a suggestion u can ignore it all)

This might help you :

```
Select name as dname , count(*) from designer where id in 
(Select designer_id from game where id in 
(Select started.id from started where started.gameid not in 
(Select finished.gameid from finished))) 
group by dname
```

Comment: Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: i made a little change , try it again

Comment: Thanks. No error now, but also empty results. I think your suggestion to change the database design is for the best.

Comment: I guess this should work , but let me ask you something , diffrence between game id and id in started and finished tables , if a game is finished , the id in both tables are same yeah?

Comment: If a game is finished, the `game_id` is the same in both tables, but there is no reason to assume that the `id` will be the same.

Comment: so the id column in both tables are complelty useless and thats just for your counting info?

Comment: Yes, it's just an auto-incrementing id

Comment: Oh now i got your design , Its full of redundancy , let me rewrite my query

Comment: In your example data , the finished tables shows 2 rows , but its not clear thats the game with started_id from 1 to 4 ? is that correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195349/discussion-between-pourya-fard-and-gluepear).

Answer (score 0):

Following SQL may help you

```
SELECT designer.name, COUNT(started.game_id) AS total 
FROM started 
LEFT JOIN game ON started.game_id = game.id 
LEFT JOIN designer ON game.designer_id = designer.id 
LEFT JOIN finished ON finished.game_id = started.game_id
WHERE finished.id IS NULL
GROUP BY designer.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what your are doing, you want to know the number of unfinished games by designer.name. You want something like this:

```
SELECT Games.name, Count(Games.id) AS GamesNotFinished
FROM
(SELECT designer.name, game.id
  FROM started 
  INNER JOIN game ON started.game_id = game.id 
  LEFT JOIN designer ON game.designer_id = designer.id 
  LEFT JOIN finished ON finished.game_id = started.game_id
WHERE finished.game_id IS NULL) AS Games
GROUP BY Games.name
```

After you comment I've created a simple working sample in Db Fiddler, showing that this does work (The clause "WHERE finished.game_id IS NULL" is to display only those who don´t exist).Try it out please in [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c2mMcqWM3tstpbYEC2G8nF/1)

That said, looking back to you tables, I down understand why you need two tables to manage just two states.
You will probably be better off by addind two columns of type int, "started" and "finished" to the game table.

Then your app could simply set started = 1, and finished = 1 when those occurred, and your select will simple check table games where started = 1 and finished = 0, I'm I wrong?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work, probably because `finished.game_id` is never `null`. If a game is not finished, there is no entry for it in the `finished` table.